# How to add n columns below first column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, tools, cut-command

I have a tab-separated data:

```
1-1 2-1 3-1 ...
1-2 2-2 3-2 ...
1-3 2-3 3-3 ...
1-4     3-4 ...
        3-5
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
1-4
2-1
2-2
2-3
3-1
3-2
3-3
3-4
3-5
...
...
```

How can I do this using awk or any other tools?

Comment: What are the actual delimiters in your file (the formatting of the site makes it look space-aligned - but it may actually be tabbed?)

Comment: delimiters are space between two columns, but each cell has value like this: 1-1 1-2 1-3 ... so on.

Comment: is there any empty cell?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' data.txt | sort -n | sed '/^$/d
```

I assumed that the data entries are separated by one or more spaces. sed simply substitutes space with line feed. The result get pipe to sort which does the sort. The last sed deletes empty lines.

Or you can use the translate command:

```
cat data.txt  | tr  " " "\n" | sort -n
```